# Override link color in custom less file, Magento2

Tags: magento2, less

I want to change the color of the links in my template.

How can I achieve this by using `_theme.less`?

Answer (score 4):

Override variable value in your active theme's `_theme.less` file like below:

```
@link__color: red;
```

You can view all variables name for override in your theme `_theme.less` at `<root_project>/lib/web/css/source/lib/variables`.